# Evaluate() not working inExcel VBA as expected

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user-defined function in an Excel VBA module. Let's say it's:

```
Function MyFunc( val1 as Double, val2 as int, val3 as int ) as Double
    MyFunc = val1 * val2 + val3
End Function
```

I also have another Function MyEval:

```
Function MyEval( formula as string )
    MyEval = Evaluate( formula )
End Function
```

In a worksheet, the cell B1 contains the following string:

```
"blah blah blah "&MyFunc(VAL,2,0)&" foobar "&MyFunc(VAL,6,5)&" do re mi"
```

Note that the quotes are part of the string, not just denoting that it is a string. In second cell, I have the following:

```
=MyEval(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"VAL",8))
```

In general this works. In the above case I would get, as expected, the string:

```
blah blah blah 16 foobar 53 do re mi
```

In some cases, however, I would get #VALUE!. When I examined those examples that failed, I would find that removing different parts would allow the string to evaluate, but that no specific part caused it to fail, i.e., just the first half works, just the second half works, and just the middle part works.

Thinking that it might be a length issue (strings are up to 200 characters), I wrote a new evaluation function, where I break the string into parts on the concatenate symbol (&), evaluate each part separately, and then concatenate the results together:

```
Function MyEval2(formula As String)

If Len(formula) = 0 Then
    Eval2 = ""
Else
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(formula, "&")
    Dim result As String
    result = ""

    Dim index As Integer
    Dim part As String
    For index = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
        part = parts(index)
        If (Left(part, 1) = """") And (Right(part, 1) = """") Then
            part = Left(part, Len(part) - 1)
            part = Right(part, Len(part) - 1)
            result = result & part
        Else
            Dim val As Variant
            val = Evaluate(part)
            result = result & val
        End If
    Next index
    Eval2 = result
End If
```

End Function

In this case, sometimes when the variable 'part' was, for example, the string

```
MyFunc(8,6,5)
```

the line

```
val = Evaluate(part)
```

resulted in 'val' being the string

```
MyFunc(8,6,5)
```

instead of the value 53.

Note: I have extensively re-written this to make it clearer.